# rank on mysql with join

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to display rank with my sql on 2 joined table, there's my mysql query to display

```
SELECT a.UserID, b.Nama,a.Matematika,a.IPA,a.IPS,a.BIND,a.BING,a.Rata,
       FIND_IN_SET( a.Rata, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( a.Rata ORDER BY a.Rata DESC ) FROM datanilaiujian )) AS rank
from datanilaiujian as a JOIN
     datauser as b
     ON a.UserID=b.UserID
ORDER BY a.Rata DESC
```

but when i execute this command, mysql return Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

list field on table datanilaiujian

```
UserID  Matematika IPA   IPS  BIND BING  Rata
1000    90         76     78.9  78  65    77.58
1001    78.9       87     67    56  78    73.38
1002    80         78.9 67  55  65.9  69.36
1003    78.9       56     77    88  90    77.97999999999999
```

list field on table datauser

```
UserID  Pass    Nama    Alamat      NoTelepon       AsalSekolah          Tanggal Masuk    NilaiUN
1000    1000    Habib   Jl.sesama   232323232323    23dsdsdsfsdfsdfsdfsdff  2017-01-13 19:35:22 Sudah
1001    1001    wisnu   jl sesama   085600336706    SMA 2 Purwokerto    2017-01-28 17:35:32 Sudah
1002    1002    Arif    Jl Sungkio  085600336706    SMA BINTEK  2017-01-28 19:30:56 Sudah
1003    1003    Akbar   Jl sesama   085600133558    SMPN 1 Purwokerto   2017-02-02 18:59:47 Sudah
```

my expected result :

```
Nama   Matematika    IPA   IPS    BIND    BING    Rata    Rank
```

Comment: And what is the `JOIN` there for?  You are not using any columns from `b`.  Is it just a filter?

Comment: You'd post your expected result, that would be better to sort up your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem.  Your subquery is saying `a.Rata`.  This refers to the *outer* table.  I suspect that the `GROUP_CONCAT()` is then confusing MySQL, so the subquery is not interpreted as an aggregation query.

However, you should move the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT a.*,
       FIND_IN_SET( a.Rata, l.list) AS rank
from datanilaiujian a JOIN
     datauser b
     ON a.UserID = b.UserID CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( a2.Rata ORDER BY a2.Rata DESC ) as list
      FROM datanilaiujian a2
     ) l
ORDER BY a.Rata DESC;
```

This generally helps the optimizer choose the best execution plan.

Comment: this works, but i need to display Nama on datauser table

Comment: @RudiEncok . . . Then include it in the `SELECT`.  You didn't bother to put it in the query in the question.